# Invalid userID() when connecting TI SensorTag to IBM IoT Foundation via Bluemix

Tags: android, sensors, ibm-cloud, texas-instruments

I read all the other posts relating to the TI SensorTag and the IoT foundation service and still (1) cannot get it to connect and (2) find a clear answer on the following message in the registered device's connection log:

> > Invalid userID () for device auth:
> >     ClientID='d:nx0fls:St:b0b448b94b80' Oct 6, 2015 6:24:25 PM
> >
> > Closed connection from 1.152.97.51. The operation is not
> >     authorized. Oct 6, 2015 6:24:25 PM
> >
> > Invalid userID () for device auth:
> >     ClientID='d:nx0fls:St:b0b448b94b80' Oct 6, 2015 6:24:25 PM

****Device details**:**

Organisaton: nx0fls

Device Type: St
Device ID: b0b448b94b80

I am using the Android app to push data to the IoT service, and have the following settings;

username: use-token-auth

password: "token from device registration"

device id: d:nx0fls:St:b0b448b94b80

broker address: tcp://nx0fls.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com

broker port: 1883

publish topic: iot-2/evt/sensors/fmt/json

Any help in solving this woudl be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested it here? Already includes your device ID: https://quickstart.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/#/device/b0b448b94b80/sensor/

Answer (score 0):

I believe TI is working out some kinks in their app to work with IoTF in registered device mode (as opposed to quickstart mode).  If you want to email me directly I can help investigate further - check my profile it should have valid email address.

Comment: Hi Valerie, I can't see an email for you in your profile. I am very keen to discuss this subject some more. Can you please email on enviroeye.au[at]gmail.com

Comment: I guess you can't see my email.  I created a chat room here in Stack Overflow https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/91604/discussion-between-valerie-lampkin-and-mark-morris?tab=general